# How to use aggregate function on column cotainining string values?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am using PostgreSQL, I've one column named `Result` in `Job` table,
it contains values like `2/3`, `1/3`, `2/3`.

For Example: `Job` table rows are:

```
job_id result
------ ------
1      2/3
2      1/3
3      2/3
```

I want to apply aggregate function on `result` column in such way that 
I can get result like: `5/9`

But `Result` is of text type column and we cannot directly apply `sum`/`avg`/`min`/`max` etc. function on that column.

Can anybody suggest any other approach to achieve that result using query itself?

All suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: And what should happen if the `result` column has not small numbers but say `32/6734513, 467/12345679, 1/98765432011` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM( dividend ) || '/' || SUM( divisor )
       AS FractionOfSums
     , AVG( dividend / divisor )        
       AS AverageOfFractions
FROM
  ( SELECT CAST(substr(result, 1, position('/' in result)-1 ) AS int)
           AS dividend
         , CAST(substr(result, position('/' in result)+1 ) AS int)
           AS divisor
    FROM rows
  ) AS division
```

Comment: `position('/', result)` should be `instr(result, '/')` for Oracle

Comment: Fixed the `select`. Not sure about the concatenation, though.

Comment: Concatenation should be `||` no?

Comment: @Aaron: `SUM(a) / SUM(b)` does not always equal `AVG(a/b)`. In fact, almost never, only in very special cases.

Comment: @Aaron: I guess it's up to the OP to clarify what aggregate exactly he wants.

Comment: Yes, but he didn't want the average. AVG(2,1,2) = ~1.3 but in his example, he gets 5.

Comment: @Aaron: `(2/3+1/3+2/3) /3 = 5/9` though!

Comment: @ypercube: for position function we can't use comma, so finally the query would be like: 

 SELECT SUM( dividend ) || '/' || SUM( divisor )
       AS FractionOfSums
FROM
  ( SELECT CAST(substr(result, 1, position('/' in result)-1 ) AS int)
           AS dividend
         , CAST(substr(result, position('/' in result)+1 ) AS int)
           AS divisor
    FROM rows
  ) AS division

Comment: @SmartSolution: Yes, thank you, edited that. So, you wanted the two sums after all.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to ypercube's excellent answer, if you want to simplify the fraction you'll need to find the greatest common divisor.

Here's pseudo code for a stored function that can generate this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION gcd(x int, y int) RETURNS int DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE dividend int;
  DECLARE divisor int;
  DECLARE remainder int;

  SET dividend := GREATEST(x, y);
  SET remainder := LEAST(x, y);

  WHILE remainder != 0 DO
    SET divisor = remainder;
    SET remainder = MOD(dividend, divisor);
    SET dividend = divisor;
  END WHILE;

  RETURN divisor;
END
```

Now you can rewrite the query into:

```
SELECT (dividend/MyGCD) || '/' || (divisor/MyGCD) as FractionOfSums
  , AverageOfFractions 
FROM ( 
  SELECT 
    SUM( dividend ) as dividend
    , SUM( divisor ) AS divisor      
    , gcd(SUM( dividend ),SUM( divisor )) as MyGCD 
    , AVG( dividend / divisor ) AS AverageOfFractions 
  FROM ( 
    SELECT CAST(substr(result, 1, position('/', result)-1 ) AS int) AS dividend
        , CAST(substr(result, position('/', result)+1 ) AS int) AS divisor    
    FROM rows ) AS division 
) as Elements
```

Note that `GCD` is a very slow function.